# L2 boundness of Integral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

If we have the kernel $k(x,y)=\frac{x}{(y-x)^2}$ for $(x,y)\in(0,\infty)\times(-\infty,0)$, my question is: is this operator

$$Tf(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}k(x,y)f(y)dy$$

bounded in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})$? In other words:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|Tf(x)\right|^2dx< C ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})}$$

for some $C>0$?

I tried to see if $k\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, but it seems not to be true. Not all the singular integrals have integrable kernel, but I don't know how to follow at this point. Maybe it could be related to the derivative of the Hilbert transform, but I have an "$x$" in the numerator anyways.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe it is needed to add a principal value in the definition of $T$?